# Why does UITableView auto height not work when I navigate to the SideMenuController

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I logout from my app and jump to the SideMenuController (It is a library which is under the side menu), the table view height is not working in the Home page.

Instantiate the ViewController:

```
let vC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuController") as! SideMenuController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vC, animated: true)
```

Setting up the table view height:

```
@IBOutlet weak var spicesTableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    spicesTableViewHeight.constant = spicesTableView.contentSize.height
    spicesTableView.reloadData()     
}
```

Lastly, calling table view delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add also the `heightForRowAt` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Also, instead of the `reloadData` method and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, try to use the `layoutIfNeeded` method inside the `viewDidAppear` method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    spicesTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```